# Recommended DotNetNuke module project templates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dotnetnuke

Every module I've developed is separated into 2 folders:

1. DesktopModules/[ModuleName] - contains `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` files.
2. Modules/[ModuleName] - contains a class library project with the rest of the code (`.cs` files).

I've heard that you can use a special project template that handles `.aspx`, `.cs` and much more module related file types - under one project (like some special class library). I'd like to get recommendations for a DNN module (5.0+) project template for visual studio 2008.

Comment: Unfortunately there are not enough suggested templates here to decide better or worse ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another template (with AJAX support) from code endeavors http://www.codeendeavors.com/Downloads.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the simple answer is to use a Web Application project (instead of a Web Site project) within Visual Studio.

You can also check out [Creating DotNetNuke Modules using a Web Application Project (WAP)](http://weblogs.asp.net/ianrobinson/archive/2008/10/15/creating-dotnetnuke-modules-using-a-web-application-project-wap.aspx) on [Ian's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/ianrobinson/) for some more details on how that works.

Comment: There is nothing in the Web Application Project (or the C# Template in Ian's post) that would prevent you from using AJAX, though there's nothing in there that specifically aids in using AJAX, either.  What sort of support are you wanting?  For most simple scenarios, setting your module controls to use the EnablePartialRendering setting in DNN will be all that you need to do.